# Update the mysql field according to the sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting

a simple task, but I can't figure it out. There is a Table:

| id | name | sum | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | 210 | 0 |
| 2 | Bob | 250 | 0 |
| 3 | Sam | 190 | 0 |
| 4 | Bill | 290 | 0 |
| 5 | Jack | 210 | 0 |

I need to UPDATE the PLACE
according to the maximum SUM and then the id
Those are the request :
`SELECT id, name, sum, place FROM` table`ORDER BY`sum`DESC,`id `ASC;`

According to this request, update the semi PLACE from 1++
Those places 1, 2, 3 and further throughout the table

Like this:

| id | name | sum | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | 210 | 3 |
| 2 | Bob | 250 | 2 |
| 3 | Sam | 190 | 5 |
| 4 | Bill | 290 | 1 |
| 5 | Jack | 210 | 4 |

Comment: Please post as text which we can use as opposed to images which we can't and read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks to learn how to post tidy.

Comment: umm, i do curious if [`rank()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) fits your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @n_place := 0;
UPDATE `table` SET `place` = @n_place := @n_place + 1 ORDER BY `sum` DESC, `id` ASC;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: It turned out to be simple. Update with variable + do the necessary sorting!

Comment: About rank() function - I didn't know about such a function. Thanks!

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it